# How to block access to https URLs by regex on OS X?

Tags: macos, security, blocking, url, https

Is there any way in which I can, on OS X, effectively block against access (by browsers or potentially any process) to secure URLs by regex?

E.g. deny access to: `https://example.com/foo/bar/.*`

but at the same time allow access to all other non-matching URLs under `https://example.com/`

I'm not looking for a solution which involves browser extensions, but that would work automatically for any browser and any fresh (extensionless) browser profile.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this possible on *any* system?

Comment: @Daniel why not, with the appropriate proxy?

Comment: @slhck HTTPS requests contain the path fragment of an URL in plain text? Seriously? (I know nothing about HTTPS... I always thought everything was encrypted and the requested length could be used for side-channel attacks...)

Comment: @Daniel Oh, valid point though, I didn't realize this at first! (Should look into the appropriate standards/RFCs some time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [proxy auto-config](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config) (PAC) file to do this if all your applications honor system proxy settings. It is a [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) file declaring a single function FindProxyForURL(), which provides the web browser the proxy setting for a URL. You just need to return a non-working proxy setting to prevent a connection from happening.

```
var normal = "DIRECT", blackhole = "PROXY 127.0.0.1:3421";

function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
    if(/^https:\/\/example.com\/foo\/bar\//i.test(url)) {
        return blackhole;
    }
    return normal;
}
```

You need to use a [file URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) to [load the PAC file from the local hard drive](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/web_security/connector/connector2972/PACAP.pdf#page=4). Enter this URL as the system proxy setting in the Network System Preferences panel.

This approach has been used before – see [no-ads](http://www.schooner.com/~loverso/no-ads/) for an example of such a script that blocks many URLs.